# How to retrieve the GUID of SharePoint groups

Tags: sharepoint, graph, microsoft-graph-api, sharepoint-online, spfx

I want to create an API in MS Graph to retrieve the groups:
[https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/{guid_id}/members](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/%7Bguid_id%7D/members)

How can I retrieve the GUID of SharePoint groups from the current sites and dynamically add it in the query?

Thanks!

Comment: You can list all Groups in your organization using `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups` which gives you group objects. You would get `id` for each object which is nothing but the GUID in your above call.

Comment: Let me know if it worked for you.

Comment: @ShivaKeshavVarma - if I list all the groups in my organization - actually, it doesn't list all of them. I checked with an example. But If I query all the groups that I am member of ( https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/transitiveMemberOf/microsoft.graph.group?$count=true) it's displaying the correct result.

Comment: Yes, If you use that call as well you will have that `id` property which is nothing but the GUID of a particular group.

Comment: To list all Groups there is a concept of pagination where you would be getting a nextLink which can get you next set of results. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/paging

Comment: Did it work for you?

Comment: Yes, thank you a lot! @ShivaKeshavVarma

Comment: Glad that it worked for you. Moving this to answer. :)-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can list all Groups in your organization using

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups
```

which gives you group objects. You would get id for each object which is nothing but the GUID in your above call.

To list all Groups there is a concept of pagination where you would be getting a ***nextLink*** which can get you next set of results. See this [paging document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/paging).

You can also get the groups you are member of using

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/transitiveMemberOf/microsoft.graph.group?$count=true
```

which also gives you the id's of groups.